# Pixel coordinates in Metal fragment shader

Tags: shader, fragment-shader, metal, pixel-shader

I am writing a 3D app using Metal.  For rendering in 3D I need to control each pixel.  In normal screens this seems to be working ok with the [[position]] variable passed to the shader.  But in Retina display, where there is a scaling factor, each screen-coordinate represent 2x2 (or 3x3) pixels.

Let me elaborate with iPhone 6 screen as example:  screen-coordinates is 375x667 and pixel-coordinates is 750x1334.   Here is my (test) shader code:

```
fragment half4 myFragShader(vtxOut in [[stage_in]],
                           float4 pcoord [[position]])
{    
    if(pcoord.x >187.5)    //187.5=375/2
         return half4(1.0 , 0.0 , 0.0, 1.0);  // return red
    else return half4(0.0 , 0.0 , 1.0, 1.0);  // return blue 
}
```

With the above test code, I am getting (exactly) left half of the screen as blue and right half as red.  This means the pcoord is coming in the coordinates system 375x667, not in 750x1334.

Questions:

1. Will the fragment shader be called for every pixel-coordinate? Or only for every screen-coordinate?
2. If it gets called for every pixel-coordinate, how do I access each pixel inside the fragment shader?

I tried the same with the pcoord.y (in my code above) with similar result.

Answer (score 2):

After doing a little digging, your answer to question 2 seems correct, i.e. use `in.position.xy`.

For question 1, I discovered the Metal fragment shader seems to work in **native** pixel coordinates, i.e. the pixel dimensions of the physical hardware screen.

My problem concerned clipping (discarding) pixels in the fragment shader and I was getting unexpected results because I was clipping to screen pixel coordinates and not native pixel coordinates. After this realisation everything worked fine.

So it looks like iOS uses its own screen coordinates (called points I believe) which then get rescaled to the physical hardware later on. UI input also seems to work in screen coordinates. Whereas Metal fragments work with native (hardware) screen coordinates.

I discovered I could find out the relative information (in Swift 5) using the following:

```
let systemWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
let systemHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
let systemScale = UIScreen.main.scale

let metalWidth = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.width
let metalHeight = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height
let metalScale = UIScreen.main.nativeScale
```

For my system, this gave:

```
System Screen size = 768.0 x 1024.0
      system scale = 2.0
 Metal screen size = 1536.0 x 2048.0
       metal scale = 2.0
```

So presumably to go from system screen dimensions to hardware screen dimensions we multiply by `systemScale`, whereas to go from Metal screen dimensions to system we divide by `metalScale`.

Comment: Thanks @Pixel for posting your findings.  Yes, that sounds logical.  I did not verify the relations between systemScale and metalScale until now. Thanks a lot for the explanations

Answer (score 1):

This is my own answer:

Though I could not find out why some simple projects do not give the exact pixel-coordinates in the shader code, few other projects I created did give me the coordinates in pixel-coordinates (including the screen scaling factor), i.e. in my example above, I did get `750x1334` coordinates, not `375x667`.

So, to answer the two questions I posted:

1. The fragment shader will be called for every pixel-coodinate and
2. `in.position.xy` gives the coordinates inside the shader code.

Shall update this, once I find out what was going wrong in my projects that give the coordinates in screen-coordiantes.